# Custom Dialog at the location of the button clicked on the ListView

Tags: android, listview, dialog

**-** Previously i have done showing off the custom `Dialog` on the clicking of the button on the `ListView`, but that was at a **static location**.

**-** Now i want to display the `Dialog` **dynamically** on the **location of the button click on the** `ListView`.

[image: Dialog on the ListView]

[image: Dialog on the ListView]

**-** I am not sure about how to find the location of the button on the Screen, cause the **click is absorbed by the button, so i can't get the click transferred to the Screen.**

**-** Even if `onTouch` is implemented, i am **not sure** about **how to find the location of the button which is being clicked on the** `ListView`, cause the **click is being absorbed by the button and ListView won't receive it.**

**-** So please help me find out the solution to this tricky situation.

Comment: http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/

Comment: @Nunu can you pls post this as answer as i want to accept it, its the right answer....

Comment: You can use the quick action dialog explained here: http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert the button click listener in the Adapter of ListView, or insert the Object one parameter and insert here when the button is touch and onClickListener get the Object and verify the parameter.